# Regular expression, matching between two patterns in a multiline string

Tags: python, regex

I have a multiline string, and I want a regular expression to grab some stuff from in between two patterns. For example, here I am trying to match everything between the title and date

For example:

```
s ="""\n#here's a title\n\nhello world!!!\n\nPosted on 11-09-2014 02:32:30"""
re.findall(r'#.+\n',s)[0][1:-1] # this grabs the title
Out: "here's a title"
re.findall(r'Posted on .+\n',s)[0][10:-1] #this grabs the date
Out: "11-09-2014 02:32:30"
re.findall(r'^[#\W+]',s) # try to grab everything after the title
Out: ['\n'] # but it only grabs until the end of line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> s = '''\n#here's a title\n\nhello world!!!\n\nPosted on 11-09-2014 02:32:30'''
>>> m1 = re.search(r'^#.+$', s, re.MULTILINE)
>>> m2 = re.search(r'^Posted on ', s, re.MULTILINE)
>>> m1.end()
16
>>> m2.start()
34
>>> s[m1.end():m2.start()]
'\n\nhello world!!!\n\n'
```

Don’t forget to check that `m1` and `m2` are not `None`.

Comment: The user uses `findall` which may indicate that in the same multiline string multiple matches may exist. Using multiple regex instructions may cause problems in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\n([^#].*)Posted', s, re.S)
['\nhello world!!!\n\n']
```

If you want to avoid the newlines:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^([^#\n].*?)\n+Posted', s, re.S + re.M)
['hello world!!!']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match all using one regular expression.

```
>>> s = '''\n#here's a title\n\nhello world!!!\n\nPosted on 11-09-2014 02:32:30'''
>>> re.search(r'#([^\n]+)\s+([^\n]+)\s+\D+([^\n]+)', s).groups()
("here's a title", 'hello world!!!', '11-09-2014 02:32:30')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a group match using parenthesis:

```
    result = re.search(r'#[^\n]+\n+(.*)\n+Posted on .*', s, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    result.group(1)
```

Here I've used `search`, but you can still use `findall` if the same string may contain multiple matches...

If you want to capture the title, the content and the date, you can use multiple groups:

```
    result = re.search(r'#([^\n]+)\n+(.*)\n+Posted on ([^\n]*)', s, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    result.group(1) # The title
    result.group(2) # The contents
    result.group(3) # The date
```

Catching all 3 in the same regex is much better than using one for each part, specially if your multiline string may contain multiple matches (where 'syncing' your individual `findall` results together could easily lead to wrong title-content-date combinations).

If you are going to use this regex a lot, consider compiling it once for performance:

```
    regex = re.compile(r'#([^\n]+)\n+(.*)\n+(Posted on [^\n]*)', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    # ...
    result = regex.search(s)
    result = regex.search('another multiline string, ...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group match with non-greedy search (.*?).  And give the group a name for easier lookup.

```
>>> s = '\n#here\'s a title\n\nhello world!!!\n\nPosted on 11-09-2014 02:32:30'
>>> pattern = r'\s*#[\w \']+\n+(?P<content>.*?)\n+Posted on'
>>> a = re.match(pattern, s, re.M)
>>> a.group('content')
'hello world!!!'
```